# Angular accessing nested objects values from component.html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I want to fill an HTML table dynamically with data from a passed in object with Angular.

As long as I try to access values on the "first level" of my object, the code works fine. The problem is that I can not access values from nested objects. Anyone have a workaround?

table.component.ts:

```
setTable(headers: string[],attributes: string[], obj: any) {            
    this.obj = obj;
    this.tableHeaders = headers;
    this.attributes = attributes;
}
```

table.component.html:

```
<td *ngFor="let header of tableHeaders; let i = index" >{{ object[attributes[i]]}}</td>
```

a parent component:

```
this.table.setTable(
    ['First Name', 'Phone', 'City'],
    ['name', 'phone', '??????'], // Where ???? I have tried both address.street and address[street] and nothing is displayed, and when I try address [object Object] is displayed.
     aUserObject
);
```

user.model.ts:

```
export class User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    phone: string;
    email: string;
    address: Address;
}
```

Where Address is also an object, with a property `street`.

Comment: If you want to keep using strings to refer to nested elements of your object, you'll have to split the string ('address.street' becomes ['address', 'street']), and then loop though the array to get the address from the user, then the street from the address.

Comment: @JBNizet You write: "if you want to keep using strings.." , if you have a better alternative for accessing nested elements I would really be interested! Bu apart from that I am not also sure I get where to loop through the new string array in order to find the street. Could you give an example in code? It would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use functions, instead of strings. For example, instead of using 'address.city', you would use `user => user.address.city`. That would have the advantage of being type-safe, refactorable, and much faster. The code to get an attribute using a path as a string would be in a function/method of your controller, that you would call from the view

Comment: @JBNizet Your suggestion works wonders and is great as long as it is used with interpolation, but I can not use it for two way data binding. This part of the binding does not like functions `(input)="arrowFunc = $event.target.value"`.
Do you have another suggestion?!

Comment: I can't understand what you're doing here. Edit your question, or ask another one, with a complete minimal example (and explanations) showing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JBNizet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447301/angular-using-arrow-functions-to-two-way-bind-object-properties