# Angular - Using arrow functions to two way bind object properties

Tags: angular, typescript

The following code works. It loops over an array of objects to get one per row and then for every object it loops over an array defining what should be displayed per column.

```
 <tr  *ngFor="let object of objects"
   <td *ngFor="let column of tableColumns;" > 
     {{column.attribute(object)}} //Explained bellow
   </td>
 </tr>
```

The `column.attribute` is an arrow function i.e. `object => object.a.property`. This solution was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112633/angular-accessing-nested-objects-values-from-component-html?noredirect=1#comment79846121_46112633) and is used to access properties of nested objects in interpolation.

The problem arises when I want to use this way of accessing the properties in a two way "banana in a box" data binding.

This does **not** work:

`<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="column.attribute(object)">`

---

After some experimentation I found a workaround but it is not so elegant and thus the question if this can be written nicely.

I wrote the two way data binding like this:

`<input [value]="column.attribute(object)"(input)="onInput($event, column, object)">`

The method called on `input` event:

```
private onInput(event, column, object){
        column.attribute(object, event.target.value);
    }
```

and the really bad part is that my attributes method is no longer an arrow function as above, but a normal ugly one.

```
private editPhone(user, newValue = undefined){
    if (newValue != undefined) {
      user.phone = newValue;
    }
    return user.phone
  }
```

Comment: The accepted answer explains what's wrong with banana box. An appropriate solution could be possibly proposed, but it is unclear from the question how `column.attribute(object)` is better than `object.a.property` in the first place. The latter is more performant and even has less chars.

Comment: @estus Did you check the link I provide in my question? It might answer your question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112633/angular-accessing-nested-objects-values-from-component-html?noredirect=1#comment79846121_46112633

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow function allows reading the value from the object. If you want to write a new value into the object, you need another function, taking the new value and storing it in the object:

```
<input [ngModel]="column.attribute(object)" (ngModelChange)="column.write(object, $event)" />
```

Of course, you can also use a single function acting both as a reader and as a writer, as you're doing in your question with your editPhone function.

This function can perfectly be written as an arrow function:

```
(user, newValue) => {
  if (newValue !== undefined) {
    user.phone = newValue;
  }
  return user.phone;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it can be written as an arrow function but since I have quite a lot of columns it doesn't help readability. I think I will go with the `column.write` approach. Anyway thank you once again for your answer.